# Do I need digital registration (einreiseanmeldung) in Germany if I have an onward flight from there (different PNR) and do not exit the airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, germany, frankfurt

This question arose due to my upcoming flights from Stockholm to Frankfurt and then Frankfurt to Delhi. The two flights are with different airlines and different PNRs.

- Stockholm - Frankfurt (Lufthansa, Arrives at Terminal 1 at Frankfurt)
- Frankfurt - Delhi (Air India, Departs from Terminal 1 at Frankfurt)

Germany requires a [digital registration](https://www.bundesgesundheitsministerium.de/en/coronavirus/infos-reisende/faq-tests-einreisende.html#c20270) except in some cases one of which is "transit". Does this qualify as a transit? Would I have to face immigration at Frankfurt in this case?

Comment: From the link you posted: “5. Stays of up to one day
Persons who spent less than 24 hours in a high-risk area or area of variants of concern or are entering the Federal Republic of Germany for less than 24 hours under the border traffic regime, are exempt from the obligation to register.” Have you tried to register to see if the system allows you to do so (I suspect it might not)

Comment: Hey, I tried to register, but it asks for a German address where I would stay and I do not have any such address since I won't exit the airport.

Answer (score 5):

> Does this qualify as a transit?

Yes. You don't need to fill out a registration but things will be a lot easier if you do. Lufthansa in Stockholm will need to verify that you meet all the entry requirements for Germany. The fact that you have an onward ticket for the same day doesn't matter to them. If you need an address, just use the airport or a airport hotel. There are two Hilton's right at the train station.

If you don't have the form, you need to sweet-talk the check in agent to accept your Air India ticket as proof of departure. This may or may not work and Lufthansa can deny you boarding.

> Would I have to face immigration at Frankfurt in this case?

No. It's a Schengen to Schengen flight so there are no passport controls on either end. You need to figure out how you can check in to the Air India flight. If you can do it online, you can simply stay in the secure area. If you need to see a check in agent (for document checks, for example), you can try a customer service desk (if you can find one) or doing it at the gate. The safest bet (if you have the time) is to leave the secure area and go to the regular Air India check in counter. Clearing security in Frankfurt is typically no fun, so you want to budget at least an hour for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my flight was yesterday and Lufthansa was fine when I told them I had an onward ticket, although they didn't even check it. After that it was never asked anywhere. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just changing planes in Frankfurt counts as a transit. Even transit on land (e.g. by car, train or bus) is exempt from the requirement to register. So no, you do not have to register.

You will find this confirmed on the very first page of the entry registration form:

> When do I not need to provide my details?
>
> - If you ... are only passing through Germany.

The wording of the regulation (in its official English translation):

> Section 3 (obligation to register) ... does not apply to persons who
> ... are only passing through the Federal Republic of Germany and will
> be leaving the country by the quickest route to complete their
> transit.

So as long as you are not planning an unnecessarily long stay in Frankfurt, e.g. to take a trip into the city or something like that, and are just entering to wait for your onward flight, you clearly fall into this exception from the obligation to register.

The last time I travelled from Sweden to Germany, about 5 weeks ago, I was asked at check-in wether I was going to stay in Germany or was just entering for the purpose of transit. Since I was going to stay, they wanted to see my entry registration. I would very much assume that also the check-in staff at the airport in Stockholm is aware of the difference. If they for some reason are not and demand to see an entry registration, you can always do that at the airport. It only takes a few minutes, but you do in that case indeed need to 'invent' an address, at which you are going stay in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that for the first airline, your final destination is Germany, and that they are likely to check you have all the paperwork required to enter the country. They are likely not to care about you having an ongoing flight (which you may miss or have any other issue which could cause you to have to stay in Germany).

Airlines are often more strict than the authorities (which in this case are unlikely to require the registration), because they can incur fines if they let through someone without the proper paperwork.

Since both Sweden and Germany are within the Schengen Area, you won’t go through immigration (but you’ll go through exit passport control in any case). You may however have to exit to secure area (“airside”) if you have checked luggage (which you would need to reclaim and then drop at a check in desk), or if you can’t do online/mobile check-in and the second airline doesn’t have transit desks you can reach on you mr way between the two flights.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I don't have checked luggage only cabin baggage. Also, I tried to do the digital registration but the form asks for a German address where I would stay and I do not have any such address since I won't exit the airport.

Comment: You can try to use the address of the airport or of an airport hotel.